# Cross domain Iframe cookies are not being set in safari iphone

Tags: iphone, iframe, dns

I am using Iframe to show a cross domain page. I don't own the domain so I cannot do anything on that domain. Now that domain is setting some cookies and it shows image if cookie is set now if I change the Safari's setting on iphone to Always it works and if I set it to the "From visited" it does not work. I also tried using jquery cookies plugin to check if cookies are enabled but it does not work when the "From visited" is set in iphone safari setting. I just want to show the user a dialog if "Accept cookies" in safari is to "from visited" Or "never" if it is not possible to let cross domain iframe to add cookie in Iphone safari.